# How to set "default" AbbreviatedMonthNames? (C#)

Tags: c#, datetime-format

Is there a way of setting the default values for AbbreviatedMonthNames in C#?

e.g. on MSDN, it gives the following use for the property:

```
  CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
  DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;
  dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { "of Jan", "of Feb", "of Mar", 
                                              "of Apr", "of May", "of Jun", 
                                              "of Jul", "of Aug", "of Sep", 
                                              "of Oct", "of Nov", "of Dec", "" };  
  dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames;
  DateTime dat = new DateTime(2012, 5, 28);

  for (int ctr = 0; ctr < dtfi.Calendar.GetMonthsInYear(dat.Year); ctr++)
     Console.WriteLine(dat.AddMonths(ctr).ToString("dd MMM yyyy", dtfi));
```

But what if I wanted to use just

```
Console.WriteLine(dat.AddMonths(ctr).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

...and have it use whatever the current culture is? i.e. without having to create a new instance of `dtfi` ?

Right now, it seems if my current culture is en-GB then it works fine, but for other cultures it abbreviates the months to just numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToString()` (and Format, etc) needs a culture to format the dates/times. It can't do without it. So if you don't pass an explicit culture to use, it just takes the current thread's default culture.

Fortunately, you can change the current thread's culture pretty easily - just set [`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Note that you might be tempted to simply modify that culture - but you can't. It's read-only. You need to [`Clone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) it first, then modify the clone, and then set it back.

Voila! Vanilla `ToString()` now uses your specific settings.

```
var ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
var dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;
dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { "of Jan", "of Feb", "of Mar",
                                          "of Apr", "of May", "of Jun",
                                          "of Jul", "of Aug", "of Sep",
                                          "of Oct", "of Nov", "of Dec", ""};
dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Naturally, you only need to do this once per thread.

Comment: Thanks, but I've discovered another issue. The CurrentCulture is reset in many areas around the application with code along the lines of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture)`, which overrides my change of the AbbreviatedMonthNames even if the `culture` value is the same as the one I had already set (e.g. "ja-JP") . Is there a way of setting the default for the actual culture itself, rather than just a particular instance of it? Rather than having to put in the above code in a large number of locations?

Comment: @colmde - Sorry, not that I'd know of. A better question is - why are there so many calls for changing the current culture? That smells like a bad design choice. If your application is very multi-culture, then you should use the overrides which take a specific culture. If it uses just one culture, then just set it once at the start. Otherwise you're really making a mess, because the changed culture sticks around even after you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could build a `string.Format` call to get the format you want:

```
string.Format("{0:dd} of {0:MMM yyyy}", myDate);
```

In your code, it would look like this:

```
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < dtfi.Calendar.GetMonthsInYear(dat.Year); ctr++)
{
    var myDate = dat.AddMonths(ctr);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:dd} of {0:MMM yyyy}", myDate))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a month name by creating a date of that month and formatting the result

```
dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[12];
for (int m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
    dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames[m] = new DateTime(2015, m, 1).ToString("MMM");
}
```